# Updating Exchange 2010 - Rollups or Service Packs first?

Tags: exchange-2010, service-pack

I have a single Exchange 2010 server that is still running SP1 RU3.  I'm thinking of updating to SP2 but do I have to update all the SP1 Roll Up packs before upgrading to SP2?  Or does SP2 include all of the SP1 Roll ups already?

I couldn't seem to find any definitive info on Microsoft's technet site so I'm wondering if you guys can help me out here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do SP 2 and then any post SP2 rollups ( I believe the latest is Rollup 3). All previous Rollups for SP1 are included in SP2 as per:

[Issues That Are Fixed in Exchange 2010 SP2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh672189.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Service Packs are sufficient, as they *should* include all the previous updates, or at least the ones that haven't been superseded.  So do SP2, and then look for updates afterwards, or you'll be installing a bunch of patches that are already included in SP2.  No harm in doing the rollups first, but it does take extra time and effort for no benefit.

That said, I did once have an infuriating conversation with MS tech support about a missing update and their answer to why it wasn't installed in the previous service pack was "*some service packs are more all-inclusive than others.*"  So it doesn't always hold true, but it's the general case that MS Service Packs include all previous, relevant updates.